# OpenCover showing no result asp net core 461

Tags: asp.net, powershell, xunit, opencover

I'm trying to get OpenCover working for our asp net core project, targeting full framework 461. We are using XUnit as the testing framework. However when I run my powershell script, the result only shows coverage on the test classes in my test folders and not coverage on the classes inside source folder.

How do I get coverage on those files?

My solution is structured like this  src/API and test/API.UnitTests

The important port my script looks like this:

```
&$openCoverPath\OpenCover.Console.exe `
    -target:$xunitPath\xunit.console.x86.exe `
    -targetargs:".\test\API.UnitTests\bin\Debug\net461\API.UnitTests.dll -noshadow -nologo" `
    -register:user `
    -oldstyle `
    -mergeoutput `
    -hideskipped:File `
    -searchdirs:".\test\API.UnitTests\bin\Debug\net461\" `
    -output:$coverageReportFile

# Generate HTML report from results with ReportGenerator
&$reportGeneratorPath\ReportGenerator.exe `
    -reports:$coverageReportFile `
    -targetdir:$coverageReportFolder
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<DebugType>Full</DebugType>
```

in the api csproj file did the trick.